# Tabbed Interface in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabbed

I am currently working on an application with a tabbed interface. I want to be able to split the workspace horizontally or vertically by dragging a tab to one edge of the window.

For example, open two tabs: http://666kb.com/i/b65vvbusbxhvgy8mf.png

Then drag one tab to the bottom of the screen and drop it. A second tabcontrol should appear: http://666kb.com/i/b65vvjnd1ylz54jdz.png

How can I achieve that with C# and WPF in .NET 3.5?
I think Photoshop does that and I'm sure many other applications too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check out [AvalonDock](http://www.codeplex.com/AvalonDock), maybe this can help you to get into the right direction.

Comment: Das sieht sehr gut aus, danke! :)

Answer (score 1):

The Actipro tabbed workspace control is very elegant and I haven't seen any bugs myself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few libraries out there for this. Other than AvalonDock, there's [Sand Dock](http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sanddockwpf/) and [Infragistics WPF Controls](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx). I've used both. Both have had their share of bugs. At this point I am using the Infragistics controls and they're getting better in every release.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll stay with AvalonDock, looks good so far and it's free :)

Comment: I'm using the Infragistics one but I'm not very impressed. It's expensive to purchase a license just for the dock, and it's somewhat complicated. They also don't support Composite WPF applications very well either--their NetAdvantage for Composite Application Library hasn't been updated in a year.